# TextInput centered align vertically on iOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, textinput

Is there any way to center align the text **inside** the TextInput vertically on iOS? (not the TextInput itself, but its text)

The TextInput has **multiline** set to **true**.

I have tried using "textAlignVertical: center", but it doesn't work on iOS. I also need the input's height to be dynamic.

(Please refer to my code below from when reading the section below)

What I'm trying to achieve is prevent the user from seeing any changes in the UI when the Text component transforms into a TextInput.

I'm not sure if my approach of center aligning the text vertically inside the TextInput will work as I expected. Besides, I can't even find a way to achieve that. So, I'm welcome to hear any new creative ideas to approach this problem.

```
import {TextInput, Pressable, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'

function TextBlock() {
  const [editing, setEditing] = React.useState(false)
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('')
  const props = {}
  if(!editing) props.onPress = () => setEditing(true)
  return (
    <Pressable {...props}>
      {
        editing ? (
          <TextInput style={styles.text} multiline={true} onBlur={() => setEditing(false)} value={text} onChangeText={t => setText(t)}/>
        ) : (
          <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
        )
      }
    </Pressable>
  )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    fontSize: 14,
    paddingTop: 0,
    paddingBottom: 0,
    paddingRight: 0,
    paddingLeft: 0,
    lineHeight: 20,
    marginBottom: 0,
    marginTop: 0,
    marginLeft: 0,
    marginRight: 0,
    textAlignVertical: 'center',
    textAlign: 'left'
  }
})
```

Comment: what is TextInput? styled component? or react component. If you can add display: flex to your text put and then align-items: center, justify-content: center

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. Thanks anyway. TextInput is a react native component. Check the code again, I added imports.